# Division of Polynomials with real problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Mr.Aquino wants to paint the ceiling of a room that has a length of $c^2+2cd+d^2$ meters and a width of $c+d$ meters.If one can paint will cover $(c+d)^2$ square meter.what is the minimum number of cans of paint needed? Express your answer as a polynomial.

Comment: Did I edit it right?

Comment: Hint: $c^2 + 2cd + d^2 = (c+d)^2$